# How To Get Cookies From WebView?

Tags: javascript, java, android

How To Get Cookies [image]

the My Code, but Not From `WebView`

```
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
cookieManager.setCookie("http://xx.xxx.xxx.com","mid=GO ; Domain=.xxx.com");

String cookie = cookieManager.getCookie("http://xx.xxx.xxx.com");

Log.d("VOGA", "cookie ------>"+cookie);
w.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
w.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
w.loadUrl("http://xx.xx.xxx.com");
setContentView(w);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of long and boring methods, I think you can get cookies from the WebView directly (for example, after user login) by:

```
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
  String myCookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
}
```